# Filter by date range if the date column field type is text/keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

After reading some online posts, I came to know that we can't edit field type in an index once it's created unless we completely delete it.

How can I write a query to convert the field type "text" to "date", in my filter condition?

***Mapping:***

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "address": {
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "state": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "zipcode": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "enddate": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "customerstatus": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "customerid": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***Query:***

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "32081",
            "fields": [
              "address.zipcode"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "FL",
            "fields": [
              "address.cityname",
              "address.state"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "customerstatus": "pending"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "enddate": {
                     "gte": "2018-09-01", 
                     "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                      "lte": "2021-07-01"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "customerstatus": "active"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "enddate": {
                     "gte": "2021-04-27",
                     "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "terms": {
          "customerstatus.keyword": [
            "Inactive",
            "cancelled"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "customerid":1,
    "customerstatus": Active,
    "address": {
                        "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
                        "state": "FL",
                        "zipcode": "32081"
                    },
    "enddate": "2022-07-15" 
},
{
    "customerid":2,
    "customerstatus": Pending,
    "address": {
                        "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
                        "state": "FL",
                        "zipcode": "32081"
                    },
    "enddate": "2016-01-01" 
},
{
    "customerid":3,
    "customerstatus": Pending,
    "address": {
                        "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
                        "state": "FL",
                        "zipcode": "32081"
                    },
    "startdate": "2020-06-01",
    "enddate": "2021-06-01" 
},
{
    "customerid":4,
    "customerstatus": Pending,
    "address": {
                        "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
                        "state": "FL",
                        "zipcode": "32081"
                    },
    "startdate": "2021-01-01",
    "enddate": "2022-01-01" 
}
```

I am expecting customers 1 and 3 to be in my Output result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't change the name and type of a field, you can always add another multi field.

For instance, you could add a `date`-multifield to your `enddate`-field, so that your mapping eventually looks as follows:

```
  "enddate": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      },
      "date": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    }
  },
```

Then you would need to make sure that the new field also gets populated. You can achieve this by executing an `update_by_query`-request, like

```
POST <my_index>/_update_by_query
```

After that you only would need to change the field-name in your query from `enddate` to `enddate.date`.

Looking at your mappings, you may want to consider improving them by replacing the default entries by entries which match your particular use case. Currently it seems that all string values are mapped as text & keyword multi fields, suited for full text and exact match search. If this is really what you need, then all is fine.

Comment: Apologies @Daniel Schneiter, I didn't check the message earlier. I will try the solution you have recommended. 
Yes, I need to map as text & keyword for an exact match search.